# EntityFramework Extended how to update using values in a dictionary

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-6

I am trying to update a table using following code

```
Dictionary<int, decimal> myDictionary = GetDictionary();

Context.Persons
.Where(t => mydictionary.Select(s => s.Key).Contains(t.Id))
.Update(t => new Person { Salary = mydictionary[t.Id] });
```

> Unable to create a constant value of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2[[System.Int32, mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.Decimal, mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]'.
>   Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this
>   context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is EF can't translate your dictionary instance to sql notation. As the exception said, you can only use a primitive type collection or an enumeration type collection. To avoid this issue do the projection first to obtain the keys and then declare your query:

```
 var keys= mydictionary.Select(s => s.Key);
 var query=Context.Persons.Where(t => keys.Contains(t.Id));
 foreach(var person in query)
 {
   person.Salary=mydictionary[person.Id];
 }
 Context.SaveChanges();
```

I don't know how is implemented the `Update` method, I guess is a custom extension method, but I want to warn you that Linq is used for consult data, not to modify them, that's way I use in my code a `foreach` to modify each person returned by the query, and at the end I call the `SaveChanges` method to save all the changes.

Comment: I am using entity framework extended library which has the Update() and Delete() extended methods.

Comment: I didn't know it, thanks. Anyway I don't see how you can update the each person with the proper salary using the dictionary or another collection inside your query.

Comment: I take a look inside the code of [`Update`](https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended/blob/master/Source/EntityFramework.Extended/Batch/SqlServerBatchRunner.cs) method in the EntityFramework extended library, and it works pretty much as [SQL UPDATE](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp), so with this method you can update several columns, but using the same values for all the rows that meet the Where condition. So I'm afraid with this method you can't update each person with its proper salary.